# Explode pandas dataframe singe row into multiple rows across multiple columns simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` as

```
df
       col1 act_id col2                                                                                                 
   --------------------
0  40;30;30   act1 A;B;C
1  25;50;25   act2 D;E;F
2     70;30   act3 G;H
```

I want to break each record in such a way that values in column `col1` and `col2` explode into multiple rows but such that the first value in `col1` after splitting upon `';'` corresponds to the first value in `col2` after splitting upon `';'`. So my `desired_df` should look like this:

```
desired_df
       col1 act_id col2                                                                                                 
       ---------------
    0  40   act1   A
    1  30   act1   B
    2  30   act1   C
    3  25   act2   D
    4  50   act2   E
    5  25   act2   F                                                                                                  
    6  70   act3   G                                                                              
    7  30   act3   H
```

**NOTE:** this is not the same as [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows)
 as here the exploding/splitting of one record is not just across one column but the need is to split or explode one row into multiple rows, in two columns simultaneously.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you can use `unnesting(df,['col1','col2'])` from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939 after splitting the cols by `;` like `df.col1=df.col1.str.split(';')` and same for col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way to do this

```
df2.set_index('act_id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.col1.split(';'),x.col2.split(';')), axis=1).stack().dropna().reset_index()

df2.columns = ['col1','act_id','col2']
```

```
  col1 act_id col2
0  A    act1   40 
1  B    act1   30 
2  C    act1   30 
3  D    act2   25 
4  E    act2   50 
5  F    act2   25 
6  G    act3   70 
7  H    act3   30
```

Comment: this solution worked for this particular df, although when i tried running this on a bigger dataframe with about 1M rows, i got the error as `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` I don't understand because even the bigger original dataframe had just these columns.

Comment: try the updated..problem might be related to duplicated index values, if the update doesn't works then try breaking the code and running it step by step, will help u debug the problem (do post on which step u faced the error)

Comment: I tried to break it down step by step and I found that the error occurs at the `set_index('act_id')` method. I removed all other methods and still got the error as `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` Is there any other way to get to the desired result...?

Comment: i still end up having the error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Answer (score 0):

the idea is col1 and col2 should be exploded and then merge on index and join back to the original dataframe.

```
df1 = df.col1.str.split(";").apply(pd.Series).stack().droplevel(1).reset_index()
df2 = df.col2.str.split(";").apply(pd.Series).stack().droplevel(1).reset_index()
df12 = pd.merge(df1, df2[0], left_index=True, right_index=True)
df12.columns = ["index", "col1", "col2"]

pd.merge(df12, df["act_id"], left_on="index", right_index=True)
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'droplevel1'`

Comment: `droplevel(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

A generic function could be:

```
list_cols = {'col1','col2'}
other_cols = list(set(df.columns) - set(list_cols))
exploded = [df[col].explode() for col in list_cols]
desired_df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(list_cols, exploded)))
desired_df = df[other_cols].merge(desired_df, how="right", left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Please strsplit the col 1 and 2 before calling above function